# how to specify the pdfbox.apache filename when downloading/exporting?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, pdfbox

Just wondering is there any way to name the document after you specify the doc.name to a template

```
  PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(play.Play.application().resource("/templates/" + FileName));

  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            doc.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
            doc.close();
```

therefore, when you download PDFBOX rendered file, the name of the pdf file can not be specified. is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Play framework.

If you want to enable users to download the file and provide it a filename, then you need to set the HTTP header

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf
```

When the browser sees this header, the user will get a dialog box to save the file and will suggest the name to be myfile.pdf.